# Consolidate sheets, but add newly inserted rows at the end of the already consolidated data

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following issue: I am looking to consolidate 9 sheets of different and growing size, but whenever new rows are inserted, these should go at the end of the already consolidated data. Example. I have 5 rows in 9 sheets. I consolidate them and the master sheet has 45 rows of data. If I insert 2 rows in sheet1 and 1 row in sheet 3, then I should have in master 45rows already consolidated, then the 2 rows from sheet1 and the one row from sheet3. and this will keep going over time.

The code below adds the newly entered rows at the end but takes data from all sheets.

I have more sheets that the master and those 9 which makes it unreliable to use sheet.count:

```
Sub consolidate()
Dim r As Range, d As Object, n&
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For n = Sheets.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set r = Sheets(n).[c2]
    Do While r.Value2 <> ""
        d(r.Value2) = 1
        Set r = r(2)
    Loop
Next
Sheets("Master").[c2].Resize(d.Count) = Application.Transpose(d.keys)
End Sub
```

If am changing this line:

```
For n = Sheets.Count To 1 Step -1
```

To either one of the below lines, it doesn't add the newly entered rows at the end of the current data, but it consolidates it again and add it in the midle:

```
For n = 9 To 1 Step -1

For n = 1 To 9 Step 1
```

Why it happens and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Could you provide the file with mock data to get more clarity?

Comment: The piece missing from your code is determining which rows have already been consolidated into the summary sheet.  Couple of ways to do that: 1) search the summary sheet for each row before copying it. 2) add a marker to each row in the data sheets when it's copied.  Only copy if that marker is missing